# How to convert flutter CameraImage to png or jpg with proper colors and rotation?

Tags: flutter

I am using the `camera` flutter lib and `startImageStream` method of the controller
Every X ms I get one `CameraImage` input and want to save this in file as jpg/png

I am using some code found online but it has 2 issues

1. It is grayscaled and without any colors
2. It is rotated 90 degree anti-clockwise

The code that I am currently using is

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;

Future<List<int>> convertImageToPng(CameraImage image) async {
  imglib.Image? img;
  if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) {
    img = _convertYUV420(image);
  } else if (image.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888) {
    img = _convertBGRA8888(image);
  }

  imglib.PngEncoder pngEncoder = imglib.PngEncoder();

  // Convert to png
  List<int> png = pngEncoder.encodeImage(img!);
  return png;
}

// CameraImage BGRA8888 -> PNG
// Color
imglib.Image _convertBGRA8888(CameraImage image) {
  return imglib.Image.fromBytes(
    image.width,
    image.height,
    image.planes[0].bytes,
    format: imglib.Format.bgra,
  );
}

// CameraImage YUV420_888 -> PNG -> Image (compression:0, filter: none)
// Black
imglib.Image _convertYUV420(CameraImage image) {
  var img = imglib.Image(image.width, image.height); // Create Image buffer

  Plane plane = image.planes[0];
  const int shift = (0xFF << 24);

  // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
  for (int x = 0; x < image.width; x++) {
    for (int planeOffset = 0;
        planeOffset < image.height * image.width;
        planeOffset += image.width) {
      final pixelColor = plane.bytes[planeOffset + x];
      // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF
      //           A   B   G   R
      // Calculate pixel color
      var newVal = shift | (pixelColor << 16) | (pixelColor << 8) | pixelColor;

      img.data[planeOffset + x] = newVal;
    }
  }

  return img;
}
```

method `convertImageToPng`

I need a cross-platform ios+android method to convert CameraImage to jpg/png with proper colors and without rotating.

```
    _controller?.startImageStream(
      (image) {
        final asPng = await convertImageToPng(image);
        // todo then I save this on disk or uploa
      },
    );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ciao Krist. "It is rotated 90 degree anti-clockwise" nuk ka lidhje me kodin qe po ben. Varet nga hardware-rotation qe ka vete telefoni te kameras dhe ka menyra qe te rrotullosh imazhin ne menyren e duhur. Per sa i perket imazhit prej camera dhe te trasformosh ne png/jpg mundet ta besh thjeshte prej librerise "image.dart"

Comment: Pershendetje Gent, po ne CameraPreview me del e kthyer tamam kur e ruaj me del me kend -90 grad e rrotulluar. Kurse me ate libari po perpiqem ta konvertoj e me dal grayscale pa ngjyra. Nese ke ndonje shembull funksional mund ta komentosh e ta provoj se spo i gjej zgjidhje te shpejte

Answer (score 1):

To capture and save images you can use as follows.

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;
```

Then by your method:

```
_controller?.startImageStream((CameraImage image){
  Uint8List imageBytes = image.planes[0].bytes;
  //convert bytedata to image
  imglib.Image bitmap = imglib.decodeImage(imageBytes.toList());

  //then save on your directories use path_provider package to get all directories you are able to save in a device
  File("pathToSave").writeAsBytesSync(imglib.encodeJpg(bitmap));

  // or as png
  File("pathToSave").writeAsBytesSync(imglib.encodePng(bitmap));
});
```

Or as an alternative:

```
// get picture as cross platform file as an alternative more easy (without passin by _controller.startImageStream)
XFile xfile = await _controller?.takePicture();

// get bytedata of it
Uint8List imageBytes = await xfile.readAsBytes();

//convert bytedata to image
imglib.Image bitmap = imglib.decodeImage(imageBytes.toList());

//then save on your directories use path_provider package to get all directories you are able to save in a device
File("pathToSave").writeAsBytesSync(imglib.encodeJpg(bitmap));

// or as png
File("pathToSave").writeAsBytesSync(imglib.encodePng(bitmap));
```

To rotate by the right side you can use this, passing bytedata's As UintList:

```
void saveImageFromUint8List(Uint8List data, int width, int height, String pathToSave) async {
  
    try {
      // Here you can use read_exif package
      final Map<String, IfdTag> exifData = await readExifFromBytes(data.toList());
      imglib.Image  source = imglib.decodeImage(data);
      if (source != null) {
        if (exifData.length > 0) {
          final IfdTag? imgOrientation = exifData['Image Orientation'];
          if (imgOrientation != null) {
            int rotation = 0;
            switch (imgOrientation.values.firstAsInt()) {
              case 6: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = 90;
                break;
              case 3: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = 180;
                break;
              case 8: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = -90;
                break;
            }
            if (rotation != 0) source = imglib.copyRotate(source, rotation); //or specify this parameter for newest version of  , angle: rotation);
          }
        }
        if (source.width != width || source.height != height) {
          File("pathToSave").writeAsBytesSync(imglib.encodeJpg(source));
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // log(e.toString());
    }

  }
```

And to get rotated image by passing the original you can use:

```
Future<imglib.Image> getRotatedByTheRightSide(imglib.Image image) async {
    imglib.Image result = image;
    try {
     
      if (image != null) {
        // Here you can use read_exif package
        final Map<String, IfdTag> exifData = await readExifFromBytes(image.getBytes());
        
        if (exifData.length > 0) {
          final IfdTag? imgOrientation = exifData['Image Orientation'];
          if (imgOrientation != null) {
            int rotation = 0;
            switch (imgOrientation.values.firstAsInt()) {
              case 6: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = 90;
                break;
              case 3: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = 180;
                break;
              case 8: // Make constants for it read about EXIF metadata
                rotation = -90;
                break;
            }
            if (rotation != 0) result = imglib.copyRotate(image, angle: rotation);
          }
        }
      }
    
    } catch (e) {
      // log(e.toString());
    }
    
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but is it possible to use startImageStream ? I need to use that because am previewing in real-time with `CameraPreview` to the user the image as well so only taking pictures on particular intervals does not help in my case. Need to convert `CameraImage`

Comment: Code updated. Vec te mira miku im..

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply but unfortunately does not work for me. One image has more than one plane and your code is using only planes[0], https://ibb.co/PrYbB0Y 3 planes one cameraImage. Also am having some other issue but will check if can use the rest of the code at least for the rotation. Faleminderit

Comment: I think the issue is more complicated because the image format is different in android and ios based on the platform and not sure if the exif and rotation data are same. Also the colors are not shown even with plane[0[

Answer (score 0):

After working for like one week I managed to got a function that converts `Yuv420` `CameraImage` to `png` with colors, BUT the image has bad rotation, is inverted upside down (I think -180 degrees)

My improved COLORFUL function is. I still need to understand how to rotate properly the image

```
imglib.Image _convertYUV420toImageColor(CameraImage image) {
  const shift = (0xFF << 24);

  final int width = image.width;
  final int height = image.height;
  final int uvRowStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
  final int uvPixelStride = image.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

  final img = imglib.Image(height, width); // Create Image buffer

  // Fill image buffer with plane[0] from YUV420_888
  for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
      final int uvIndex =
          uvPixelStride * (x / 2).floor() + uvRowStride * (y / 2).floor();
      final int index = y * width + x;

      final yp = image.planes[0].bytes[index];
      final up = image.planes[1].bytes[uvIndex];
      final vp = image.planes[2].bytes[uvIndex];
      // Calculate pixel color
      int r = (yp + vp * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round().clamp(0, 255);
      int g = (yp - up * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - vp * 93604 / 131072 + 91)
          .round()
          .clamp(0, 255);
      int b = (yp + up * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round().clamp(0, 255);
      // color: 0x FF  FF  FF  FF
      //           A   B   G   R
      if (img.boundsSafe(height - y, x)) {
        img.setPixelRgba(height - y, x, r, g, b, shift);
      }
    }
  }

  return img;
}
```

Comment: What is boundsSafe?